# LinkedList in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a solution for the following problem. I have an Excel file that I read with Pandas. Column A contains an identifier and column B also contains Identiers, but the identifiers in column B are linked to the identifier in Column A. example:

`+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |
+----------+----------+
| ID1      | ID5      |
+----------+----------+
| ID1      | ID6      |
+----------+----------+
| ID1      | ID7      |
+----------+----------+
| ID2      | ID8      |
+----------+----------+
| ID2      | ID9      |
+----------+----------+
| ID3      | ID8      |
+----------+----------+
| ID3      | ID9      |
+----------+----------+
| ID3      | ID10     |
+----------+----------+
| ID3      | ID11     |
+----------+----------+`

So now I want to have ID1 linked to ID5, ID6 and ID7. ID2 linked to ID8, ID9 etc

In Java I would use the linked list. What should I use in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to achieve here. Could you be more specific? Perhaps give an example of the Java code you'd use and the folks here can find an equivalent in Python?

Comment: You could make a LinkedList in python. However a dict seems like the most natural way to do it in my opinion. Python has built-in support for them. Look them up

Comment: That's not a linked list, in Java or any other language. Seems to be a mapping.

Comment: You could go a lot of ways with this.  A dict would be the simplest but least powerful way.  A database would be the most complex, but most powerful.  A healthy middle ground may be a class which has a name and a reference to another class of the same type.

Comment: Use a dictionary = {  "ID1" : ["ID5","ID6","ID7"], "ID2" : ["ID8", "ID9"] }; dictionary["ID1"] .append("ID9999")

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a defaultdict with set?

```
from collections import defaultdict
ident_pair_dict = defaultdict(set)

for ind, row in df.iterrows(): # df is the pandas dataframe you read
    ident_pair_dict[row['Column A']].add(row['Column B'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using pandas to read, you can construct the dictionary with pandas methods:

```
df.groupby('Column A')['Column B'].agg(lambda x: list(x)).to_dict()
Out[42]: 
{'ID1': ['ID5', 'ID6', 'ID7'],
 'ID2': ['ID8', 'ID9'],
 'ID3': ['ID8', 'ID9', 'ID10', 'ID11']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict(df.groupby('Column A')['Column B'].apply(list))
```